# Solicitando permissões de execução no Android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Estou trabalhando num `app` integrado aos serviços do `GoogleMap`. O `app` estava funcionando perfeitamente porém quero adicionar os controles de `permissões` para uso na `API23` (`Android Marshmallow)`.

Estudei a parte de `permissões` presentes no `developer.android` mas não entendi como realizo a integração no meu código.

Preciso de ajuda para implementar:

- As duas requisições de permissão presentes na classe GPSTracker
- Controle para trabalhar com as APIs inferiores a 23

Abaixo as duas condições presentes na classe que precisam das permissões de requisição

```
// if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return TODO;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
 * app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Ola, tente colocar isto em cima do método @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M), é possível que resolva seu problema. http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#M